# How to set managed meta data value when term is under another term

Tags: 2013, development, term-store, managed-metadata-service

I have a list containing managed meta data field which is reading data from following term store (picture given below):

[image]

I am trying to set field value using C# code as below but getting error

**Error**

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter
>   name: index

```
TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);  
TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Meta Data"];  
Group group = termStore.Groups["DemoGroup"];  
TermSet termSet = group.TermSets["Contoso Departments"];  
Term term = termSet.Terms["Finance"]; //error is on this line
```

If I change above line to following then it works fine. It seems since Finance is under Accounting so I cannot directly write its name and has to define some kind of path.

```
Term term = termSet.Terms["Accounting"]; //this line works fine
```

How do I update value of "Finance"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that in complex structures you could have multiple terms in the same term set with the same label (e.g you could have `Finance` under `Marketing` as well).

To just pick the first hit based on the label, you could do this:

```
//....
TermSet termSet = group.TermSets["Contoso Departments"];  
TermCollection terms = termSet.GetTerms("Finance", true);
if (terms.Count > 0) {
  Term term = terms[0];
}
```

To get it from the parent, you could get the child term like this:

```
Term parent = termSet.Terms["Accounting"];
Term term = parent.Terms["Finance"];
```